# I'm passing the 'item' parent/children and when I manipulate it changes the default value in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

need help. I got a Card component that executes a function passing 'item' and setting insides a State. And my Modal component receive that 'item' and render on screen. Besides, when I manipulate on modal component the items values it changes the default value on Card component.

```
# this is my HomeScreen and the function that sets the item value.

    const handleModalVisibleProduct = (item) => {
        setModalData(item)
        setModalVisibleProduct(!modalVisibleProduct)
}

 Then I pass to ProductsModal item

<ProductModal
  products={products}
  modalData={modalData}
  modalVisible={modalVisibleProduct}
  handleCloseVisibleProduct={handleCloseVisibleProduct}
  handleAddCart={handleAddCart}
/>
```

Comment: I assume item is an Object which means you are using a reference to the object which means mutating it directly will effect all components that are using that reference. Depending on how complex your object is you might just be able to get away with spreading the object to create a new reference: `setModalData({...item})`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is because it uses the same reference of the `item's` object. You would have to change it's reference to get the required result like

```
const handleModalVisibleProduct = (item) => {
    setModalData( {...item} );
    ....
}
```